# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time --> Xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hey so I've just started using Xcode and I don't really know a lot about Swift. I followed an online tutorial on how to create a Tic Tac Toe App on IOS using SwiftUI.
My Problem is the following:
At some point, an error shows up that suggests I **"try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"**

Here's the part of my code where it shows up:

```
var body: some View {       
        VStack{
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating:
                                        
                
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 15), count: 3), spacing: 15){
                
                
                ForEach(0..<9,id: \.self){ index in
                    
                    ZStack{
                    
                        if moves [index] == "X"{
                            Color.orange
                        }
                        else {
                        Color.yellow
                        }
                    
                        
                    Color.white
                        .opacity(moves[index] == "" ? 1 : 0)
                        
                    
                        
                        Text(moves[index])
                            .font(.system(size: 50))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .opacity(moves[index] != "" ? 1 : 0)
                    }
                    .frame(width: getWidth(), height: 140)
                    .cornerRadius(18)
                    .rotation3DEffect(
                        .init(degrees: moves[index] != "" ? 180 : 0),
                        axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
                        anchor: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/,
                        anchorZ: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/,
                        perspective: 1.3
                    )
//                    Whenever tapped adding move...
                    .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        
                        withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5)){
                            
                            if moves [index] == ""{
                            moves[index] = isPlaying ? "X" : "0"
                            isPlaying.toggle()
                            }}
                    })
                }
            }
            
            .padding(15)
            
        }

 }
//        Whenever moves updated it will check for winner...
    
        .onChange(of: moves, perform: { value in
                    
                checkWinner()
            })
            
            .alert(isPresented: $gameOver, content:{
                
                Alert(title: ("Winner"), message: Text(msg), dismissButton: .destructive(Text("Play Again"), action: {
                    
                    //resetting all data...
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5)){
                        
                        moves.removeAll()
                        moves = Array(repeating: "", count: 9)
                        isPlaying = true
                        
                    }
                }))
                
            })
}
```

Comment: *error shows up that suggests I "try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"* - this is a good suggestion and a sign that your view may be too complex. Even if the error may in some cases be misleading, try to follow the suggestion.

Comment: At a minimum, your braces don't match. The `}` before `.onChange` matches the `{` at `var body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Alert` is incorrect. You're passing Strings rather than Texts. Also check your {} pairings; the one before `.onChange` is unbalanced.

The way you debug this is to do as the error tells you to. Split up the View into smaller Views. Cmd-Shift-A, Exact Subview is very helpful for this. When the Views are smaller, the compiler has a better chance of providing a good error message. Splitting up a View into smaller sub-Views is good practice anyway. Views are extremely cheap in SwiftUI, and are intended to be relatively simple.